# Is there a name for a "non-rectangular matrix"?

Tags: mathematics

According to Wikipedia a [matrix in the mathematical sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_%28mathematics%29) is a rectangular array of numbers.

So this:

```
  1 2 3 4  
  5 6 7 8 
  7 8 9 10
```

would be an example for a matrix, while the following would not be a matrix:

```
  1 2 3
  4  
  7 8
```

What would be a good term for the latter, which is also a 2-dimensional field of numbers like a matrix but not rectangular?

---

Regarding the comment that I could just add zeros, actually that is not possible and would be a different thing, since this does come from a technical background where any element of one row can be chosen at random and increasing the length of one row has other side effects that aren't intended.
It's also not a partial matrix the elements in the shorter rows really are not there and are not free to be chosen.

Comment: Put zeros in the empty spaces and call it rectangular. That's what mathematicians do.

Comment: @John: Actually, mathematicians make a distinction between a missing number and a zero. Mathematicians aren't that careless.

Comment: Suggested migration to [math.se]

Comment: ‘sparse matrix’?

Answer (score 6):

With respect to Peter Shor (!!!) I think that a partial matrix is simply a rectangular matrix with some unknown entries, not a truly non-rectangular matrix.

In computer science I've heard such a matrix described 5 or 6 times as a "ragged array."

http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2011-March/055208.html

https://www.google.com/#q=ragged+array

Comment: I love the term 'ragged array' and intend to broaden its usage.

Comment: With over 30 years (in North America) as a computer programmer, I've never heard the term *ragged array*, though in the C/C++/Java/C# community the term *jagged array* is frequently used.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is not a "rectangular array" of numbers, it is **not** a matrix. There's not such thing as a non-rectangular matrix.

The number set in the OP's example is such that it can be represented in a rectangular matrix either by:

- assuming all the missing elements to be zeros, or
- assuming all the missing elements to be immaterial in the given case (will not influence the results)

The first of the above options gives the usual regular matrix (nothing special about it), while the second gives a 'partial matrix'.

Answer (score 0):

It's called a *partial matrix*. Googling "partial matrix" yields [this quote](http://books.google.com/books?id=EOflkS9ruxcC&pg=PA171&lpg=PA171&dq=%22partial+matrix%22&source=bl&ots=Vg3hvpcXWo&sig=B-y4EQMjjxDwWZ4llx42-ZEKvpw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1IjkUp2AE8PJsQSu9IGgCw&ved=0CEYQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22partial%20matrix%22&f=false).

> By a partial matrix we mean a rectangular array, the entries in certain locations of which are particular, known elements of *S*, while the remaining entries are unspecified and free to be chosen from *S*.

Answer (score 0):

### The correct answer is jagged array and ragged array means the same thing but is less common according to a Google phrase search.

I wanted to accept Brian Gordon's answer after adding the above information which was rejected without comment resulting in losing a better written piece with links.